# PHPJasperXML not working when using functions in JasperReports

Tags: php, yii, jasper-reports

I am using PHPJasperXML to create pdf reports in yii. http://www.simitgroup.com/?q=PHPJasperXML . I was able to create the pdf file successfully. But if I use any of the functions in the *JasperReports* then it is not working.

For example I have created group in the report and want to round the total in the group footer. Here is the code new `$V{totalamount_1}.round(MathContext(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP))`. If i use this code then the page is showing blank in PHPJasperXML. In the preview of *iReport* designer it is showing correctly.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas No. it doesn't support that. Instead I used Jasper Server and integrated with php